# r add points and point labels to a level plot

Tags: r, raster, levelplot

I'd like to plot points and labels of the points on top of a levelplot. Here's a simple example.

```
library(raster)
library(rasterVis)
library(latticeExtra)
r <- raster(matrix(runif(100), 10))
crs(r) <- "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
p = c("one", "-2", "three", "four", "five")
lat = c(.2, .4, .6, .8, .9)
lon= c(.2, .4, .6, .8, .9)
df <- data.frame(lat = lat, lon= lon, z = p)
coordinates(df) <- ~lon+lat
crs(df) <- crs(r)
```

With the `raster r` and `SpatialPointsDataFrame df`, I've tried a variety of modifications to the structure below, including with and without {} around the function inside

```
levelplot(r) +
  latticeExtra::layer({panel.points(df, size=3)})

levelplot(r) +
  latticeExtra::layer({sp.points(df, size=3)})

levelplot(r) +
latticeExtra::layer({points(x = df$lon, y = df$lat, pch=20)})
```

Comment: Check out [this answer](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2010-April/233921.html). Both solutions there worked for me